# Firefox adds 2px extra padding in input text and submit

Tags: html, css, firefox

> According to the answers below: this is best the solution:
>   .text { line-height: 15px; } input::-moz-focus-inner {border:0; padding:0; margin-top:-1px; margin-bottom:-1px;} Thank you all.

I know that there are some similar questions on Stackoverflow. Because none of the answers works for me, and I have been researching this issue for almost a week but no luck, I decide to post this question. Please help.

Lets say I have a submit button and a text box, Firefox always adds 2px extra padding inside the elements, I tried many solutions I found on the net but none of them works.

Test the code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/4f2duwud/7/

**HTML:**

```
<form action="http://google.com">
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Go to Google">
  <input type="text" class="text">
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
a.button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial;
}
.text {
  padding:3px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.submit {
  padding:3px;
  border:1px solid gray;
}
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="text"]::-moz-focus-inner, 
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner { 
  border:0 !important; 
  padding:0 !important;
}
```

**Screenshot - Firefox:**
[image]
**Screenshot - Chrome:**
[image]

Comment: Your problems might be system-specific, provide some screenshots

Comment: This is the box model of submit button showing on Firefox: http://screencast.com/t/V6I20PvuDXo
This is the box model of submit button showing on Chrome: http://screencast.com/t/kqUnSec9e

Comment: Actual screenshots of page itself would be better, browser developer tools might report size differently,  On side note you can Edit question itself to provide additional info about question.

Comment: I just added 2 screenshots above. Thank you

Comment: Updated it looks good in Firefox, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicilty setting up the `line-height` to `15px` or `17px` or whichever works for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer but line-height doesn't fix the issue. Actually it is not related. I have tried it before.

Comment: Is it the horizontal padding or the vertival padding, the issue here?

Comment: Yes, it is. Zer00ne's answer fixed the issue for the button, but doesn't fix the text box issue.

Comment: I just tried again and height-line fixed the text box issue. Thanks. For submit button please add "margin-top:-2px;"

Comment: The `line-height` fixes it for me even for the submit button. Can you try that again as well?

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

https://jsfiddle.net/Lv1cb2xr/

```
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top:-2px;
    line-height: 17px ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It fixes the button height but doesn't fix the text box height. Also, "margin-bottom: -2px" should not be here. If you put it in, the height of the button gonna be 13px.

Comment: A button like all of it's input cousins are inline, so I think the top and bottom margins do not affect the height... I think it's line-height that does.

Comment: Bro, please edit your answer. "margin-top:-2px" is a must, but "margin-bottom:-2px" and "display: inline-block" are not necessary. For the text box, use "line-height:15px" will fix the issue. Thank you. I HATE FIREFOX TOO.

Comment: The OP says `line-height` doesn't work...I see this: https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NDU0MTIyXzI0NDc2MzY

Comment: What do you mean by the OP?

Comment: OP = Original Poster = You, sir. Anyways, take a look here: https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NDU0MTI3XzI0NDc2ODE

Comment: I'm sorry. Padding and border don't matter here. As I stated above. The best solution is adding "line-height:15px" for the text box and "margin-top:-1px; margin-bottom:-1px" for the button. And the issues are solved. Please try https://jsfiddle.net/Lv1cb2xr/13/

Comment: Do you use a Mac? The resolution on a Mac is superior to that of a PC. I don't see any discernible difference still. https://zer00ne.tinytake.com/sf/NDU0MTMxXzI0NDc3NDU

Comment: I have a mac book Air but it's old and doesn't have a Retina screen to test it. I did try on my iPad and iPhone, it leads me to a ton of other issues. The height-line seems working but I think "margin" is the better way to fix the issue.  I'm good so far. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: My boss uses a Mac, she forgets I use a PC then she wants me to adjust this or that and then it looks dramatically different in a PC. Even an older model has has better resolution than most current PC. Glad you got working.

Comment: Both of you might find this enlightening.  https://www.zdnet.com/article/former-mozilla-exec-google-has-sabotaged-firefox-for-years/  Mozilla's resources have been swamped fighting fires not of their making, while Google have been able to throw massive resources at Chrome

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me for the text input (Firefox version 86) was setting the background-color:

```
.text {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: White
}
```

Once that's in place then you can set the padding and firefox will respect it.

I don't know why `background-color: White` works while `border: 1px solid gray` (as you had in your post) doesn't.

I can reproduce my results in the linked jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/Lv1cb2xr/). Setting `border: 1px solid gray` in the fiddle *does* persuade firefox to respect the padding - apparently different to the OP's experience.

It seems like a firefox bug to me, though no doubt if I were to report it then mozilla would tell me it's in the original css spec, therefore they can't do anything about it but hey why don't I consider contributing to the next round of the spec? That's what happened the last time I reported a bug. But I'm not bitter - after all was said and done, it turned out that they were perfectly correct. Wait a minute, No, actually I am still bitter. Why am I still bitter? I don't know, I just am.

The default style seems like it might be copied off the firefox chrome location bar, so maybe there's problems with inappropriately shared code.